# When would actor_tpye be "app" or "service_broker"?

Tags: cloud-foundry, audit, cloudfoundry-uaa

The CF [events api](http://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/242/events/list_all_events.html) lists an "actor_type" field for events, which can be one of:

- service_broker
- system
- user
- v3-process

What is an example of an audit event's actor type being each of the above? Where is the documentation, at a higher level than a summary of the REST endpoints, and in more detail than  [this](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/concepts/security.html#logging), for someone trying to consume this api?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`actor_type` represents what initiated the event. Similarly, `actee_type` is the resource that is being acted upon.

**user**: Most events (e.g. starting/stopping/deleting an app) will have `actor_type` "user", since the event was triggered by a user action.

**service_broker**: Some audit events are triggered by service brokers. Examples are registering a service offering or a service plan.

**system**: System is used when there is not a clear actor. There is currently a bug filed to investigate usage of this `actor_type`: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/132099009

**v3-process**: This was recently changed to be "process" in cf v245. This `actor_type` (along with the `actor_type` "app") is only used when the process/app crashes. There is also a bug around this `actor_type`: https://www.pivotaltracker.com/story/show/132098945

I could not find any documentation for audit events other than the API docs. How are you trying to consume the events API?